# AWS Step Function Distributed Map state "Label"

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am using the Distributed Map state in my Step Function for the first time. It's breaking on the "Label" key value pair which (from what I understand) gives the Map Run ARN a custom label.

```
   "All-Records":{
    "Type": "Map",
    "InputPath": "$.sign_ups",
    "ItemsPath": "$.map_data",
    "Parameters": {
        "signUpData.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
    },
    "MaxConcurrency": 1,
    "Label": "$.signUpData.Id",
    "End": true
    ...
}
```

All the documentation I have read seems to indicate that I need to give it a string value (eg - "Label": "SignUpData"). I'd really like the custom label to be the Id from the specific record in signUpData. Does anyone know if this is even possible? If so, I'd really appreciate being pointed in the right direction or to some documentation that demonstrates it. Thanks!